# Angular project Karma/Jasmine tests fails on GitHub Action under Google Chrome on Ubuntu

Tags: angular, google-chrome, testing, karma-jasmine, github-actions

In my Angular project I try to use Google Chrome for testing with Karma & Jasmine in a GitHub Action.

The Google Chrome start with multiple errors, and then dies after some tests. I tried several tips from StackOverflow ansers in this topic, but nothing helped.

I use this versions:

- Chrome 99.0.4844.51 (latest at this time)
- Karma 6.3.16
- Angular 13.2.3 (I think it's not relevant, but I don't know)

I have this `karma.conf.js` file:

```js
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 500000,
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: 'reports/coverage',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html', subdir: 'report-html' },
        { type: 'lcov', subdir: 'report-lcov' }
      ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'ChromeHeadless', 'ChromeHeadlessCI'],
    customLaunchers: {
        ChromeHeadlessCI: {
          base: 'ChromeHeadless',
          flags: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-gpu']
        }
    },
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

Here is my GitHub Action yml file:

```yaml
name: Angular test
on: [push]
jobs:
  ng-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: npm ci
      run: npm ci
    - name: Angular test in production mode
      run: npm run test:ci
```

In the `package.json` this is the scripts part:

```json
"test:ci": "ng test --watch=false --code-coverage --source-map true",
```

And I get this errors:

```
> ng test --watch=false --code-coverage --source-map true

- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
- @auth0/angular-jwt [es2015/esm2015] (git+https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt)
- ngx-bootstrap/tabs [es2015/esm2015] (git+ssh://git@github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap.git)
- @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome [es2015/esm2015] (https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome)
- ddata-ui-common [es2015/esm2015] ()
- ddata-ui-dialog [es2015/esm2015] ()
- @tinymce/tinymce-angular [es2015/esm2015] (https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-angular.git)

- ngx-color-picker [es2015/esm2015] ()

- ngx-material-timepicker [es2015/esm2015] (https://github.com/Agranom/ngx-material-timepicker.git)
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
10 03 2022 14:44:41.942:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.3.16 server started at http://localhost:9876/
10 03 2022 14:44:41.953:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome, ChromeHeadless, ChromeHeadlessCI with concurrency unlimited
10 03 2022 14:44:41.958:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
10 03 2022 14:44:42.055:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
10 03 2022 14:44:42.141:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
10 03 2022 14:44:43.220:INFO [Chrome Headless 98.0.4758.102 (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket eilZCAlj3zsV4RbPAAAD with id 4879597
10 03 2022 14:44:43.239:INFO [Chrome Headless 98.0.4758.102 (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket 03Ia71912SRh3xC_AAAC with id 64299573
10 03 2022 14:44:44.357:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
    [0310/144442.711534:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[0310/144442.711623:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)

10 03 2022 14:44:44.357:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stdout: 
10 03 2022 14:44:44.357:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stderr: [0310/144442.711534:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[0310/144442.711623:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)

10 03 2022 14:44:44.394:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
10 03 2022 14:44:44.819:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
    [0310/144444.585530:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[0310/144444.585587:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)

10 03 2022 14:44:44.819:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stdout: 
10 03 2022 14:44:44.819:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stderr: [0310/144444.585530:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[0310/144444.585587:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)

10 03 2022 14:44:44.823:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2).
10 03 2022 14:44:45.296:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
    [0310/144445.046018:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[0310/144445.046104:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)

10 03 2022 14:44:45.297:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stdout: 
10 03 2022 14:44:45.297:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stderr: [0310/144445.046018:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[0310/144445.046104:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)

10 03 2022 14:44:45.299:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up.
Chrome Headless 98.0.4758.102 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 530 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)

Chrome Headless 98.0.4758.102 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 530 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome Headless 98.0.4758.102 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 530 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome Headless 98.0.4758.102 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 530 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome Headless 98.0.4758.102 (Linux x86_64): Executed 1 of 530 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.505 secs)
Chrome Headless 98.0.4758.102 (Linux x86_64): Executed 1 of 530 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.503 secs)
Chrome Headless 98.0.4758.102 (Linux x86_64): Executed 1 of 530 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.505 secs)
Chrome Headless 98.0.4758.102 (Linux x86_64): Executed 1 of 530 (skipped 509) SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.503 secs)
Chrome Headless 98.0.4758.102 (Linux x86_64): Executed 1 of 530 (skipped 529) SUCCESS (1.435 secs / 0.505 secs)
Chrome Headless 98.0.4758.102 (Linux x86_64): Executed 1 of 530 (skipped 529) SUCCESS (1.584 secs / 0.503 secs)
Chrome Headless 98.0.4758.102 (Linux x86_64): Executed 1 of 530 (skipped 529) SUCCESS (1.435 secs / 0.505 secs)
TOTAL: 2 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 2 SUCCESS
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-project@11.0.0 test:ci: `ng test --watch=false --code-coverage --source-map true`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-project@11.0.0 test:ci script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-03-10T14_44_49_345Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

As you see tests started, and after 2 tests it's die. But there are 530 tests written.

Any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dunno if GitHub action is same like Jenkins. But on Jenkins you need to run test with --browsers=ChromeHeadless. And the error looks like that GitHub is trying to open Chrome.

So try to change your test:ci in package.json

```
"test:ci": "ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadless --progress=false --watch=false --code-coverage --source-map=false",
```

Answer (score 4):

For GitHub Actions, As of 27th August 2022, the command changed again!

```
"test:ci": "ng test --no-watch --no-progress --code-coverage --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI",
```

Also be sure to have karma conf setup correctly in `karma.conf.js`:

```
browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessCI'],
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeHeadlessCI: {
    base: 'ChromeHeadless',
    flags: ['--no-sandbox']
  }
}
```

Here's the [link](https://angular.io/guide/testing#configure-project-for-github-actions) to the documentation.

Comment: wrong answer
ng test --no-watch --no-progress --browsers=ChromeHeadless this is from documentation

Comment: Just because the command may have changed again, don't label my answer as wrong. Feel free to update the answer